# Dependencies of Django Project

Tags: python, django, dependency-management, setup.py, install-requires

I created a `setup.py` and `setup.cfg` like explained in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app).

Now I am unsure how to add dependencies to my project.

If someone installs my code, other tools like Pillow should automatically get installed.

I read that `install_requires` is the right way (not `requirements.txt`), but how to specify this?

The file `setup.py` looks pretty generic, and all content is in `setup.cfg`.

But examples I see all have their list of dependencies in `setup.py` via `install_requires`.

How to specify the dependencies of a Django project?

Comment: what do you mean by specifying dependencies of Django project

Comment: @iklinac If I install the project via pip, then the dependencies like Pillow should get installed.

Comment: you can add all the requirements your package needs in install_requires

Comment: @iklinac Do you have an example of how to put the dependencies into setup.cfg?

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/setup.cfg#L43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit odd that the Django docs on this are lacking. But yes, `install_requires` argument to `setup()` or `install_requires` key in `setup.cfg` are the way to go.

You should depend on Django and if you're relying on Pillow, pillow as well.

You can still use requirements.txt and if you want to be future friendly (as setup.py is on its way out - but that will take a long time), it's recommended to do so.

Putting that all together, I would add:

`requirements.txt`

```
Django==maj.min.patch
Pillow==maj.min.patch
```

`setup.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup
import os.path


def read_requirements():
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "requirements.txt")
    with open(path, "rt") as f:
        requirements = f.read()

    return requirements.splitlines(keepends=False)


setup(install_requires=read_requirements())
```

Comment: Could you please provide a link where I can find more about "setup.py is on its way out". That is new to me.